# Add an element to a list, the output is none

Tags: python, list

I'm very confused about a situation. Why I cannot assign a list to a variable. Can someone explain it to me?

```
a =[1,2,3,4]
b = a.insert(0,1)
print(b)
```

the output is

```
None
```

Comment: Because insert works in place and returns None

Comment: Now try `print(a)`.

Comment: The `insert()` method does not return any value. You are inserting the element in list `a`

Comment: The python docs are a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the replies that you got, if it is the list b that needs to be updated but not the list a, you should proceed as such:

```
a =[1,2,3]
b = list(a)
b.insert(1,20)
print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 4):

The insert() method only inserts the element to the list. It doesn't return any value.